# Spring Secuirty Oauth 2 - multiple user authentication services

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My application provides oauth2 token service identical to this one provided in the following github project: https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider

It is based on Spring Security OAuth2.

I provided my custom implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
<bean id="userService" class="org.example.core.service.DBUserServiceImpl" />
```

and the following user authentication manager:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Now I would like to provide other method of user authentication (other UserDetailsService), for example:

```
<bean id="otherUserService" class="org.example.core.service.LDAPUserServiceImpl" />
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a way how to do it in documentation. On the request level I would like to distinguish which method (which user service) to use by either:

- query parameter
- http header (e.g. RealmName)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` to configure multiple entry points. Which means you can have multiple ways of authenticating. Following is the sample code:

**DBUser entry point:**

```
public class DBUserAuthencticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.commence(request, response, authException);
    }
}
```

**LDAP entry point:**

```
public class LDAPAuthencticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
         super.commence(request, response, authException);
    }
}
```

Then you need to create `RequestMatcher`s to pick the correct entry point (based on header/realm name):

**DBUser request matcher:**

```
RequestMatcher dbUserMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {       
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Logic to identify a DBUser kind of reqeust
    }
};
```

**LDAP user requset matcher:**

```
RequestMatcher ldapMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {     
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Logic to identify a LDAP kind of reqeust
    }
};
```

Now we need to add these matchers and entry points to `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint`. In runtime `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` picks up the entry point and does the authentication based on the matcher which return `true`.

```
DBUserAuthencticationEntryPoint dbUserEntryPoint = new DBUserAuthencticationEntryPoint();
LDAPAuthencticationEntryPoint ldapEntryPoint  = new LDAPAuthencticationEntryPoint();

LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher,AuthenticationEntryPoint> entryPoints = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher,AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
entryPoints.put(ldapMatcher, ldapEntryPoint);
entryPoints.put(dbUserMatcher, dbUserEntryPoint);

DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint  = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoints);
```

Now map the `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` to `HttpSecurity` in the `configure()` method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
            authorizeRequests().
                regexMatchers("/login.*").permitAll().
                regexMatchers("/api.*").fullyAuthenticated().        
        and().
            formLogin().loginPage("/login").
        and().
            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

**Configure the provider manager:**

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(provider1, provider2);
}
```

Comment: OK, this will work if I am able to redirect to my custom authentication pages (for example depending on the HTTP RealmName header).

Unfortunately I do not provide authentication pages, but OAuth API only. So when request comes I need to choose appropriate authentication provider basing on the RealmName header and authenticate using credentials from Authorization http header.

Comment: No, this will work with any kind of authentication process. I have just taken form based login for demo purposes. Remove the form based login code and set the authentication provider by calling `http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)`

Comment: OK, but then I would like to use standard Oauth flow and say org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager to user specific authentication manager. I am not able to do it from authentication entry point.

Comment: I have modified the entry point classes to invoke the `commence()` method on the parent class and I have added the way to configure multiple providers. When the authentication process is triggered form commence method, the respective providers are triggered. Spring will iterate an Authentication request through a list of AuthenticationProviders. AuthenticationProviders are usually tried in order until one provides a non-null response.

Answer (score 3):

I found different solution than solution provided by Mithun.

Application context contains user authentication manager initiated with different authentication providers:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customerAuthProvider" />
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="adminAuthProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

where customerAuthProvider and adminAuthProvider are extensions of DaoAuthenticationProvider with different userDetails Service:

```
<bean id="customerAuthProvider" class="org.example.security.authentication.provider.CustomerAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>

<bean id="adminAuthProvider" class="org.example.security.authentication.provider.AdminAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="otherUserService" />
</bean>
```

All you need to do is to override "supports" method that indicates whether current authentication provider is able to handle specific authentication:

```
public class CustomerAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean supports ( Class<?> authentication ) {
        return CustomerUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

public class AdminAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean supports ( Class<?> authentication ) {
        return AdminUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

At the end you need to extend token granter. In my case I extended ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter which means that it supports "password" grant:

```
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="client-details-service" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="customPasswordTokenGranter"/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

You can use TokenRequest object to distinguish which Authentication class to instantiate (AdminUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken or CustomerUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)

```
public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter extends ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter {

    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication ( ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest ) {
        Map parameters = tokenRequest.getRequestParameters();
        String username = (String) parameters.get("username");
        String password = (String) parameters.get("password");

        String realmName = (String) parameters.get("realm_name");

        Authentication userAuth = createAuthentication(username, password, realmName);
        try {
            userAuth = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(userAuth);
        } catch ( AccountStatusException ase ) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException(ase.getMessage());
        } catch ( BadCredentialsException e ) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException(e.getMessage());
        }
        if ( ( userAuth == null ) || ( ! ( userAuth.isAuthenticated() ) ) ) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException("Could not authenticate user: " + username);
        }

        OAuth2Request storedOAuth2Request = getRequestFactory().createOAuth2Request(client, tokenRequest);
        return new OAuth2Authentication(storedOAuth2Request, userAuth);
    }

    private Authentication createAuthentication ( String username, String password, String realmName ) throws InvalidGrantException {
       // TODO: decide basing on realm name
    }
}
```